# How to highlight webelement in selenium webdriver not using javascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automated-tests

I want to highlight web element using selenium web driver but i don't want to use JavaScript Executor for the same. if i am using java script executor my DOM is getting change. that is the reason i don't want to use it. is there any alternate way to highlight web element? please suggest me a way to do this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you  mean by "my DOM is getting change"? and JavaScriptExecutor is the only available way to highlight an element in WebDriver

Comment: I mean to say adding border to web element changes it's size which is causing problem in my framework. so i want alternative way to highlight the web element.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I don't know whether this will change your DOM and framework.

```
          `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.color='red'", webElement);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.color='grey'", webElement);`
```